# Filtering NSMutableArray and saving it back in itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nspredicate

I have my `uitableview` data loaded from a `nsmutablearray` but I want to filter is as well. data is loading perfectly but now I need to apply filtering function on it and reload table. here is my code so far that I wrote for filtering but its not working

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate;
    for (int i=0; i<TableArray.count; i++) {
        float hotelDistanceFloat = [[[TableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_distance] floatValue];
        NSInteger hotelPrice = [[[TableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_price] integerValue];

        sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%ld <= %d AND %f <= %d)" , (long)hotelPrice, numberOfBudget, hotelDistanceFloat,numberOfDistance];
        TableArray = [[TableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy];

    }
```

`numberOfBudget` and `numberOfDistance` are simple int values getting from uislider. `TableArray` is my mutablearray having all the tabledata in it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return TableArray.count;
}
```

these are the values that my nsmutablearray contains

```
NSLog(@"Name : %@",[[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_name]);
NSLog(@"City : %@",[[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_city]);
NSLog(@"Price : %@",[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_price);
NSLog(@"Distance : %@",[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_distance);
NSLog(@"Image : %@",[[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_image]);
NSLog(@"Stars : %@",[[TableArray objectAtIndex:1]xmlhotel_stars]);
```

all these values are STRINGS

Comment: you are not predicting properly, there is no caparison with array data?

Comment: hotelDistanceFloat and hotelPrice are array values from array! sorry i didnt get it please would you explain bit more.

Comment: Can you display the what value contain your array.

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: Is  your object  [TableArray objectAtIndex:1] is a NSDictionary ?

Comment: no its not a NSDictionary

Comment: Is it a model object, I mean a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: Ok. Is **xmlhotel_distance** this a macro or attribute of the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121312/discussion-between-arunit21-and-vix-hunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can **remove the for loop**, you don't need to assign array and create predicate each and every time.

```
   NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(xmlhotel_price.intValue <= %d AND xmlhotel_distance.floatValue <= %f)", numberOfBudget, numberOfDistance];
   NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[TableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate]];
```

Comment: reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000003e82'

Comment: Cool, the attribute is string, so converted to intValue / floatValue will fix the crash :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact problem you are facing but this peace of code looks suspicious:

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate;
for (int i=0; i<TableArray.count; i++) {
    float hotelDistanceFloat = [[[TableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_distance] floatValue];
    NSInteger hotelPrice = [[[TableArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_price] integerValue];

    sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%ld <= %d AND %f <= %d)" , (long)hotelPrice, numberOfBudget, hotelDistanceFloat,numberOfDistance];
    TableArray = [[TableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate] mutableCopy];
}
```

You should rather use an Array that contains dictionary and apply filter from predicate to that. There should be no need for loop in order to sort the content.

Plus reload the table once you get the filtered array.

Comment: can you please explain how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Your faults

1. You are filtering the array while enumerating the array.
2. Predicate values are choosen from array which is to be filtered.

What should you do:

1. Get the values for predicate from input (hotelDistanceFloat,numberOfDistance).
2. apply predicate like:

_

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(hotelPrice <= %d AND numberOfBudget <= %d)" , hotelDistanceFloat,numberOfDistance];

TableArray = [[TableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate].mutableCopy]
```

Comment: where should i put this code?? how it will get hotelPrice?? if i put it like this?

Comment: your need to get the filtering values from input from where you set the filters.